# Send input to child in server program

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, server

I made a simple server program which accepts multiple connections and awaits input from the console. It is then meant to send this input to one of the clients which are connected.

I need a way for the user to chose which client to send this input to. I'm using `os.fork()` to spawn children to handle connections and I'm using pipes to send data to them. I just need a way to let the user pick which child to send data to while also outputting data to the screen from the other children.

I originally thought about changing the child's stdin and inputting data to the child process separately but it seemed a bit complicated and maybe even impossible.

Is there any simple way of achieving this? Preferably without external libraries.

EDIT: Code so far:

```
# Imports
import socket,json,os,signal,select

# Settings
CONTROL_PORT = 12345

# Variables
pipes = {}

# Functions
def send(conn,data):
    conn.send(json.dumps(data))
def recv(conn,buffer=4096):
    return json.loads(conn.recv(buffer)) 
def handleClient(conn,addr):
    print("[+] Started {} to handle conn from {}.".format(os.getpid(),addr[0]))
    # Some simple handshake to verify client  \ ___
    # Loop for receiving and sending data     /     To Do List
# Body
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", CONTROL_PORT))
sock.listen(5)
print("[+] Control Server successfully started. Awaiting connections on {}".format(CONTROL_PORT))
pipe_id = 1
while True:
    conn,addr=sock.accept()
    pipes[pipe_id] = [os.pipe()]
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid = 0:
        sock.close()
        handleClient(conn,addr)
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        pipe_id += 1
    # Also finish main loop
```

I still have many things to finish in the code but I need to figure out how to do this first for most of them.

Comment: What do you got so far? Any code examples?

Comment: @UroshT. I'll edit my question and add them.